# Deprecation Warning when using django.core.urlresolvers.reverse in Django

Tags: django, url, deprecated

I use the following code in my Class Based View

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

url = reverse('url_name')
```

`urls.py` looks as follows

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.TestView.as_view(), name='url_name'),
)
```

When doing so I got a deprecation warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Function-based generic views have been deprecated; use class-based views instead.
  DeprecationWarning
```

The warning is thrown on ' django/views/generic/simple.py:8`

Here is a stack to see what hapens:

```
-> return urlresolvers.reverse('url_name')
  /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py(476)reverse()
-> return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py(363)_reverse_with_prefix()
-> possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
  /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py(276)reverse_dict()
-> self._populate()
  /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py(265)_populate()
-> lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
  /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py(216)callback()
-> self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py(27)wrapper()
-> result = func(*args)
  /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py(92)get_callable()
-> lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
  /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py(35)import_module()
-> __import__(name)
> /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wfp/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/simple.py(6)<module>()
-> import warnings
```

What is the future way to do this? I'm currently using Django 1.4.

Comment: What does the associdated `url` line for the reversed url look like in `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0):

It's just an automated warning of Django functionality that should not be used if you're planning on migrating to a newer Django version that dropped support for this.

You can view the deprecation plan [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/)

Comment: Thanks, but thats clear to me... question is how to do it instead?

Comment: You're not using anything that's being deprecated in the snippet you showed.

Comment: Fine, thanks, thats what I also figured out... I just wondered why I got the warning. Looks like the core itself still uses some deprecated code, probably for backwards compatibility. This will we removed with the function based views, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but maybe i'm doing it the right way and i simply can ignore this warning, because the function I'm using does not rely on the function based views but simply they are  in the extended import scope of the urlresolvers module.